Use of `--upgrade` option in DBT 1.7 - `dbt deps` for package-lock.yml
I am trying to understand the introduction of package-lock.yml in the DBT Documentation for Upgrading to 1.7
However, it is not quite clear how --upgrade option works.
It seems to work the same without or without --upgrade.
If there is no change in the package.yml, package-lock.yml remains the same (w/ or w/o --upgrade)
And if the package.yml gets a new version, in both the case, the package-lock.yml gets updates with the revisions. (w/ or w/o --upgrade)
The sentence:
To retain the behavior prior to v1.7, there are two main options:
1. Use dbt deps --upgrade everywhere dbt deps was used previously.
:

Might require clarification.
